# Electorate gold badge not awarded

Tags: support, bug, badges, profile-page, electorate-badge

Today I was awarded the Electorate badge on Ask Different:

- **Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions**

After doing so I was presented with the screen saying I earned it and to track the next one.

On my profile it isn't there though:

[image]

Yet going into the which badge to track screen it says I have been awarded it:

[image]

It has been around 10 minutes and still not appearing on my profile or Achievement page.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, rather a script taking its time to fire. Tracking and achievements probably don't rely on the same scripts, hence the delay - I've witnessed that too on my profile, and the badge did come after some time. I don't know the technical details, hence this being a comment rather than an answer (or someone finding a dupe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wee, caching!

10 minutes might be too short for the automated script that updates your badges to run, or for the cache to be refreshed, but if you wait, say, an hour or more, it will be there.

Comment: As always: http://shouldiblamecaching.com